# when configuring ecb, i cant found button "save for future sessions"

Tags: button, emacs, emacs-ecb

According some article I searched with google, I install ecb and be ready for use.
But I realize I need read manual again because ecb window is empty.
So I got hints of configuring where to find my sources, after I input command

```
mx customize-option ret ecb-source-path ret 
and write ~
```

I find no button named "save for future sessions"
Where is that button?

Answer (score 1):

You can either use the **Apply and Save** button (which will affect *all* settings in that customize buffer), or for an individual setting you can select "Save for future sessions" from its **State** menu.

If "Save for future sessions" is not selectable, that would indicate that the current value of the option matches the currently-saved value, and hence there is no change to save. Changing the value should make the option available to you.

Afterwards you can confirm that the setting has been written to the `(custom-set-variables ...)` section of your .emacs file.

Comment: FYI "info" is something specific in Emacs (try `M-x info`), so you should really refer to it as the "customize" buffer.